# Applications Credentials not avaliable in Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to setup Google Cloud Vision API, I have defined a Application Credential Variable through CMD by using set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS PathToJSON however this still does not allow me to connect to Google Cloud Vision API for OCR.

I have also tried to set it manually through the windows UI, however still no luck, I created and defined a project in the Google Cloud page, and generated a credential key, when it asked me "Are you planning to use this API with App Engine or Compute Engine?", I selected No.

I am currently using Googles boilerplate code

```
public class DetectText {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    try{
        detectText();
    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void detectText() throws IOException {
    // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Programming\\Desktop\\TextDetection\\Capture.PNG";
    detectText(filePath);
}

// Detects text in the specified image.
public static void detectText(String filePath) throws IOException {
    List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();

    ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.readFrom(new FileInputStream(filePath));

    Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();
    Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Feature.Type.TEXT_DETECTION).build();
    AnnotateImageRequest request =
            AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder().addFeatures(feat).setImage(img).build();
    requests.add(request);

    // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
    // once, and can be reused for multiple requests. After completing all of your requests, call
    // the "close" method on the client to safely clean up any remaining background resources.
    try (ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.create()) {
        BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = client.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
        List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();

        for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
            if (res.hasError()) {
                System.out.format("Error: %s%n", res.getError().getMessage());
                return;
            }

            // For full list of available annotations, see http://g.co/cloud/vision/docs
            for (EntityAnnotation annotation : res.getTextAnnotationsList()) {
                System.out.format("Text: %s%n", annotation.getDescription());
                System.out.format("Position : %s%n", annotation.getBoundingPoly());
            }
        }
    }
}

static void authExplicit(String jsonPath) throws IOException {

}
```

}

I am not using a server or Google compute virtual machine.

Can someone please explain to me what the problem is, and how I would go about fixing it?

**Stack Trace**

```
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:134)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:119)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:91)
at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:67)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:142)
at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.stub.GrpcImageAnnotatorStub.create(GrpcImageAnnotatorStub.java:117)
at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.stub.ImageAnnotatorStubSettings.createStub(ImageAnnotatorStubSettings.java:156)
at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.<init>(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:136)
at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.create(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:117)
at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.create(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:108)
at DetectText.detectText(DetectText.java:54)
at DetectText.detectText(DetectText.java:36)
at DetectText.main(DetectText.java:25)
```

Comment: Do you use an IDE like IntelliJ? Did you try to restart? (Yes it's windows, if you want that the env variable are propagated, most of time a restart is required... Happy Microsoft!)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error message, it seems that the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable is not being found.

On one hand, before trying to run the [text detection sample code](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#detect_text_in_a_local_image), follow the steps outlined in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#before-you-begin) in order to discard that any of them has been skipped.

On the other hand, if you are using an IDE such as IntelliJ or Eclipse, you have to set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS global through [Windows System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0), so it can be used by the IDE. Nevertheless, when testing I had to close and reopen the IDE for the changes to take effect and the aforementioned error would not appear.

Additionally, there is also a way to specify the location of the JSON file within the code, as shown in [this example](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code). However, it is not advisable to put it that way, it is best to use the environment variables.